# Dirty read of session variables at client side in web application

Tags: jsp, session, session-scope

Summary :I have developed a login system in web application (using java,jsp & javascript).

Required Functionality :

Not allow user to login in to system from two different tabs of same browser at same time. If any user tries error msg "user already logged in".

Issue:
Step 1) When i try to login from other/2nd tab error msg is displayed (as expected) and redirected to login page again.
Step 2) Then i logout from first tab, at the backend i remove all session variables created.
Step 3) Then when i try to login from other/2nd tab login page, it is observed that i get session variables again, expected to get empty or null variables(as i already removed them at backend in logout request).

Expected : Should not get session variables again for 2nd tab login.

Comment: Since the browser tabs share the same session... When the user hits the login page the second time you should just redirect to your "home" page after login.

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are by IP and User-agent (i.e. browser). So you can't prevent multiple tabs in the same browser. Nor should you want to. If you need to do this its because you have a major flaw in your design. If you're just looking for a way to test yourself as two users, login in Chrome as one user and in Firefox as another.

Your problem with still being able to get to a page after logging out is apparently that you don't have anything like this to prevent unathenticated users from getting in:

```
String somevar = session.getAttribute("somevar");
if(somevar == null)
{
   response.sendRedirect("loginpage");
   return;
}
```

Similarly on the login page, if the user is already logged in:

```
String somevar = session.getAttribute("somevar");
if(somevar != null)
{
   response.sendRedirect("mainpage");
   return;
}
```

That way a user who is already logged in cannot fill out the login form again without logging out first.

It can also be a caching issue.  If you allow the browser to cache protected pages, then after a user logs out, if they go to the page again they may see the page because it was cached.  So, set no-cache headers:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
response.setHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
```